# Weighted aggregation of stars object

Tags: r, r-sf, r-stars

I was wondering if it's possible to adjust the following code in such a way that the `aggregate()` function takes into account the overlapping area between each *pixel* defined in a `stars` object and the "cells" used for calculating the overlap.

For example:

```r
# load packages
library(stars)
#> Loading required package: abind
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.7.2, PROJ 9.3.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

# define two grids starting from a general polygon
gpoly <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0, 0), c(1, 0), c(1, 1), c(0, 1), c(0, 0)))))
grid1 <- st_sf(data.frame(x = 1:9), geometry = st_make_grid(gpoly, n = c(3, 3)))
grid2 <- st_make_grid(gpoly, n = c(2, 2))

# convert the first grid into stars format and plot them. 
st1 <- st_as_stars(grid1)
plot(st1, reset = FALSE)
plot(st_boundary(grid2), col = "red", add = TRUE, lwd = 3)
```

[image]

Now I would like to aggregate the values defined by `st1` using `grid2` (i.e. the red cells in the figure above). The following code performs such an aggregation, but each new value is computed by taking a simple average of the values of the pixels intersecting a given cell (since the merge is performed using `join = st_intersects`).

```r
aggregate(
  st1, 
  by = grid2, 
  FUN = mean 
) 
#> stars object with 1 dimensions and 1 attribute
#> attribute(s):
#>    Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
#> x     3   4.125      6    6   7.875    9
#> dimension(s):
#>          from to point
#> geometry    1  4 FALSE
#>                                                                 values
#> geometry POLYGON ((0 0, 0.5 0, 0.5...,...,POLYGON ((0.5 0.5, 1 0.5,...
```

Is it possible to adjust the previous code such that the means are computed taking into account the area that overlaps pixels and cells? Like a weighted mean where the weights are the areas of overlap.

<sup>Created on 2023-10-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `st_interpolate_aw`, as in

```
st_interpolate_aw(st1, grid2, extensive = FALSE)
```